# Calling a closure function on an event created within the closure

Tags: javascript, html, dom, closures

I'm trying to create some select tags from within a closure function, and attach an event to them which calls another function within the closure.

Here's a very simplified version of my code:

```
var SomeClosure = function() {
    this.build = function(){
        var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
        newSelect.onchange = (function() {
            var selfRef = this;
            return function() { 
                selfRef.changeselection();
            }
        })();

        mydiv.appendChild(newSelect);
    };

    this.changeselection = function(){
        // do something
    }
}
```

All I get, however, is 'selfRef.changeselection is not a function'. Where am I going wrong?

I don't need to pass in the value of the select, just call the function. If, however, I did need to pass in its value too, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
var selfRef = this;
newSelect.onchange = (function() {
    return function() { 
        selfRef.changeselection();
    }
})();
```

The context inside immediate function is Window, so you get wrong reference. Also in this case you probably don't need IIFE at all, if this is all your code for `onchange` event handler.

Comment: Perfect. Looking at it now, it makes perfect sense. Thanks :)